# Issue with jQuery on an iFrame in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, iframe

This is a strange issue as the site works fine in every major browser. The only problem is that in the "Cotiza tu lote" section there's an iframe of a "request quote system" and that iframe causes conflicts specifically in IE. The weird part is that if you open the URL separately in IE it works. When I open the console in IE it appears that for some reason it's not loading jQuery correctly which breaks all the following functions.

The thing is that... on the site I am using a different version of jQuery and as far as I know if the "request quote system" is in an iframe there shouldn't be any issues because of cross domain protection.

I used Foundation 5 to build the site and I'm using its [Interchange](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/interchange.html) component to switch the "request quote system" to a contact form as it's not responsive.

You can go to the "Cotiza tu lote" section using [this link](http://www.kantara.com.mx/cotizador)

You can see the iframe source separately using [this link](http://www.navegantes.mx/cotizador/kantara/cotizador)

Comment: I clicked through in IE9 saw no issues bringing up and submitting the contact form after confirming the quote price. Maybe the issue is caused by a non-default security setting in IE?

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't update the thread, it was a compatibility issue of jQuery 1.10.1 for some reason when it was included in an iframe it caused conflicts. Changing the jQuery version fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by the jQuery version used in the iframe remote source. Apparently jQuery 1.10.1 causes issues when used in an iframe if using IE 9 or below. Changing the jQuery version fixed the problem.

I found the issue here http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/13980